# Creating a NumPy array directly from __array_interface__

Tags: python, numpy, pybinding

Suppose I have an `__array_interface__` dictionary and I would like to create a numpy view of this data from the dictionary itself. For example:

```
buff = {'shape': (3, 3), 'data': (140546686381536, False), 'typestr': '<f8'}
view = np.array(buff, copy=False)
```

However, this does not work as `np.array` searches for either the buffer or array interface as attributes. The simple workaround could be the following:

```
class numpy_holder(object):
    pass

holder = numpy_holder()
holder.__array_interface__ = buff
view = np.array(holder, copy=False)
```

This seems a bit roundabout. Am I missing a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Does your workaround work, or are you just speculating?

Comment: Why do you only have the the dict? Did you manually create it to expose an array?

Comment: I'd definitely just stick the dict on a wrapper object like you're doing here, though probably with an `__init__` method.

Comment: @hpaulj No the above works fine.

Comment: @Dunes Im exposing a C++ Matrix class.

Comment: So the `data` value in `buff` is not derived from another numpy array.  It's a buffer of your own creation.

Comment: @hpaulj In this example yes, but it doesn't have to be. As pointed out these data attributes are just pointers cast to an integer.

Comment: Looks like `exposes an array interface` means has a valid `__array_interface__` attribute.  Can't think of anything more direct.

Comment: @hpaulj Its just having the `array_interface` as an attribute means a few silly work arounds. I still don't understand why your example below does not work on my laptop.

Answer (score 5):

correction - with the right 'data' value your `holder` works in `np.array`:

`np.array` is definitely not going to work since it expects an iterable, some things like a list of lists, and parses the individual values.

There is a low level constructor, `np.ndarray` that takes a buffer parameter.  And a `np.frombuffer`.

But my impression is that `x.__array_interface__['data'][0]` is a integer representation of the data buffer location, but not directly a pointer to the buffer.  I've only used it to verify that a view shares the same databuffer, not to construct anything from it.

`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` uses `__array_interface__` for default stride and shape data, but gets the data from an array, not the `__array_interface__` dictionary.

===========

An example of `ndarray` with a `.data` attribute:

```
In [303]: res
Out[303]: 
array([[ 0, 20, 50, 30],
       [ 0, 50, 50,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 75, 25]])
In [304]: res.__array_interface__
Out[304]: 
{'data': (178919136, False),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (3, 4),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'version': 3}
In [305]: res.data
Out[305]: <memory at 0xb13ef72c>
In [306]: np.ndarray(buffer=res.data, shape=(4,3),dtype=int)
Out[306]: 
array([[ 0, 20, 50],
       [30,  0, 50],
       [50,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 75, 25]])
In [324]: np.frombuffer(res.data,dtype=int)
Out[324]: array([ 0, 20, 50, 30,  0, 50, 50,  0,  0,  0, 75, 25])
```

Both of these arrays are views.

OK, with your `holder` class, I can make the same thing, using this `res.data` as the data buffer.  Your class creates an `object exposing the array interface`.

```
In [379]: holder=numpy_holder()
In [380]: buff={'data':res.data, 'shape':(4,3), 'typestr':'<i4'}
In [381]: holder.__array_interface__ = buff
In [382]: np.array(holder, copy=False)
Out[382]: 
array([[ 0, 20, 50],
       [30,  0, 50],
       [50,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 75, 25]])
```

Comment: Re `data[0]` being representation of the buffer pointer. You're right, and may wish to include the numpy documentation `__array_interface__` http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.interface.html

Comment: Also, using a view (rather than a copy) of the data pointed to by the pointer rather than Python's buffer interface could lead to memory leak issues. That is, the buffer interface allows other users to keep a buffer alive, should the original owner fall out of scope. (hope that makes sense :s)

Comment: What version of python/numpy is this? I get a type error for the buffer.

Comment: @Dunes Id like to point out that one of the very large upsides of this technique is that it *is* a view. This allows you to manipulate C++ data with python and NumPy. You cannot really get a memory leak, but you can get invalid access. This is usually handled by intelligent wrapping and smart pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```py
import numpy as np


def arr_from_ptr(pointer, typestr, shape, copy=False,
                 read_only_flag=False):
    """Generates numpy array from memory address
    https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.interface.html

    Parameters
    ----------
    pointer : int
        Memory address

    typestr : str
        A string providing the basic type of the homogenous array The
        basic string format consists of 3 parts: a character
        describing the byteorder of the data (<: little-endian, >:
        big-endian, |: not-relevant), a character code giving the
        basic type of the array, and an integer providing the number
        of bytes the type uses.

        The basic type character codes are:

        - t Bit field (following integer gives the number of bits in the bit field).
        - b Boolean (integer type where all values are only True or False)
        - i Integer
        - u Unsigned integer
        - f Floating point
        - c Complex floating point
        - m Timedelta
        - M Datetime
        - O Object (i.e. the memory contains a pointer to PyObject)
        - S String (fixed-length sequence of char)
        - U Unicode (fixed-length sequence of Py_UNICODE)
        - V Other (void * – each item is a fixed-size chunk of memory)

        See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.interface.html#__array_interface__

    shape : tuple
        Shape of array.

    copy : bool
        Copy array.  Default False

    read_only_flag : bool
        Read only array.  Default False.
    """
    buff = {'data': (pointer, read_only_flag),
            'typestr': typestr,
            'shape': shape}

    class numpy_holder():
        pass

    holder = numpy_holder()
    holder.__array_interface__ = buff
    return np.array(holder, copy=copy)
```

Usage:

```py
# create array
arr = np.ones(10)

# grab pointer from array
pointer, read_only_flag = arr.__array_interface__['data']

# constrct numpy array from an int pointer
arr_out = arr_from_ptr(pointer, '<f8', (10,))

# verify it's the same data
arr[0] = 0
assert np.allclose(arr, arr_out)
```