# Behavior of ndarray.data for views in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to understand the meaning of `ndarray.data` field in numpy (see [memory layout](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#memory-layout) section of the reference page on N-dimensional arrays), especially for views into arrays. To quote the documentation:

> ndarray.data -- Python buffer object pointing to the start of the array’s data

According to this description, I was expecting this to be a pointer to the C-array underlying the instance of ndarray.

Consider `x = np.arange(5, dtype=np.float64)`.

Form `y` as a view into `x` using a slice: `y = x[3:1:-1]`.

I was expecting `x.data` to point at location of `0.` and `y.data` to point at the location of `3.`. I was expecting the memory pointer printed by `y.data` to thus be offset by `3*x.itemsize` bytes from the memory pointer printed by `x.data`, but this does not appear to be the case:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(5, dtype=np.float64)
>>> y = x[ 3:1:-1]
>>> x.data
<memory at 0x000000F2F5150348>
>>> y.data
<memory at 0x000000F2F5150408>
>>> int('0x000000F2F5150408', 16) - int('0x000000F2F5150348', 16)
192
>>> 3*x.itemsize
24
```

The `'data'` key in `__array_interface` dictionary associated with the ndarray instance behaves more like I expect, although it may itself not be a pointer:

```
>>> y.__array_interface__['data'][0] - x.__array_interface__['data'][0]
24
```

> So this begs the question, what does the `ndarray.data` give?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since `y` is non-continuous, it doesn't expose `data` (`>>>y.data
AttributeError: cannot get single-segment buffer for discontiguous array`). So I kinda cannot imagine how you're going to compare `x.data` and `y.data`. (`numpy 1.11.1` and `python 2.7.12 win32` here)
.

Comment: 192 = 3*64, just saying

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I am not getting this error from evaluation of `y.data` using numpy 1.11 on Windows and Linux using Python 3.5.2 from Anaconda distribution. What is your configuration?

Comment: 24 bytes, 192 bits?

Comment: @user40314 I only said that it returns an error for me, I couldn't know about the cause of discrepancy. Since the question couldn't be answered without finding it out, I required additional info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the number displayed by `x.data` isn't meant to be used by you.  `x.data` is the buffer, which can be used in other contexts that expect a buffer.

```
np.frombuffer(x.data,dtype=float)
```

replicates your `x`.

```
np.frombuffer(x[3:].data,dtype=float)
```

this replicates `x[3:]`.  But from Python you can't take `x.data`, add 192 bits (3*8*8) to it, and expect to get `x[3:]`.

I often use the `__array_interface__['data']` value to check whether two variables share a data buffer, but I don't use that number for any thing.  These are informative numbers, not working values.

I recently explored this in

[Creating a NumPy array directly from __array_interface__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39376892/creating-a-numpy-array-directly-from-array-interface/39377877#39377877)

Comment: Thank you for your response and for the link. My confusion was in conflating `PyArray_DATA` on C-API with `ndarray.data`.

Answer (score 3):

`<memory at 0x000000F2F5150348>` is a `memoryview` object located at address `0x000000F2F5150348`; the buffer it provides access to is located somewhere else.

Memoryviews provide a number of operations described in the [relevant official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typememoryview), but at least on the Python-side API, they do not provide any way to access the raw address of the memory they expose. Particularly, the `at whatevernumber` number is not what you're looking for.