# Constructing an array from memory address

Tags: python, numpy

I have done this function that uses ctypes to create an object with a buffer protocol that points to a specified address:

```
import numpy as np

def np_buffer_from_address(shape, dtype, address):
    import ctypes
    return np.ndarray(shape, dtype = dtype, buffer = ctypes.c_void_p.from_address(address))
```

But I wanted to know if I can do this without using ctypes. If you can do it directly with numpy

Comment: What's the source of the `address`?  In the link I show that you can use the `.data` attribute of another array.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39377877/901925

Comment: `numpy.ctypes` might help; https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ctypes.html

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid ctypes by using just the standardized [__array_interface__](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.interface.html), here's an example how it works: [Creating a NumPy array directly from __array_interface__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39376892/creating-a-numpy-array-directly-from-array-interface/39377877)
 (in fact, numpy.ctypeslib.as_array does the same under the hood, setting typestr and data appropriately)